# Fill out missing dates into associative array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date, addition

What would be the simplest way to add missing dates in array like this?
It needs to be in the correct order though & since data can't be added in associative array with `array_slice()` I didn't find a way to do it without ending up with four foeach loops with converting into multidimensional array and converting back. Thanks!

```
    Array
(
    [1.1.2016] => 10
    [3.1.2016] => 5
    [5.1.2016] => 8
    [8.1.2016] => 3
)


Array
(
    [1.1.2016] => 10
    [2.1.2016] => 0
    [3.1.2016] => 5
    [4.1.2016] => 0
    [5.1.2016] => 8
    [6.1.2016] => 0
    [7.1.2016] => 0
    [8.1.2016] => 3
)
```

Comment: No `for` / `foreach`?

Comment: `for` with a `DateTime` object, creating a new array which holds all dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `DateTime`'s `DatePeriod` we can loop through the dates **IF the dates are in the right order to start with**. If it's possible that they are not in the right order to start with, you'll have to edit the begin and end `DateTime`

```
<?php
$newarray = array(); //Our new array
$myarray = array(...); //$myarray is your array that you have
reset($myarray); //Sets array position to start
$key = key($myarray); //Grabs the key
$begin = new DateTime( $key ); //Sets the begin date for period to $begin
end($myarray); //Sets array to end key
$key = key($myarray); //Gets end key
$end = new DateTime($key); //Sets end variable as last date
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); //Includes the last day by adding + 1 day

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); //Increases by one day (interval)
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end); //Gets the date range

foreach($daterange as $date){
    $date = $date->format("j.n.Y");
    if(isset($myarray[$date]))
        $newarray[$date] = $myarray[$date];
    else
        $newarray[$date] = 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks mate! This is really nice and understandable with those comments.

Answer (score 0):

This works no matter what the order the dates are in, though maybe you're limited to a year:

```
$dates = array("8.1.2016" => 100, "2.1.2016" => 5);


$date = "1.1.2016";
$m = null;
$fixed_dates = array();
while($m <= "12"){ 
  $fixed_dates[$date] = (isset($dates[$date]) ? $dates[$date] : 0);
  $edate = explode(".",$date);
  $m = $edate[0]+1;
  $date = implode(".",array($m,$edate[1],$edate[2]));
}

print_r($fixed_dates);
```

Comment: I don't get the year thing, the variable is not used in the code.

Comment: That was from something else I was trying. I removed it.